# Dividing all observations in a data frame with a particular observation of a column with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with more than `300` rows and more than `4000` columns. A sample of the Df looks like this:

| AB | BC | DA | DC | FF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 50 | 4 | 10 | 60 |
| 10 | 20 | 10 | 5 | 20 |

I want to create another DF by dividing all the observation by `cells of column DC` so that i will have a df that looks like this:

| AB | BC | DA | DC | FF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 0.4 | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0.2 | 2 |

an Idea that came to my mind was `iterrows` but I could not find my way around it.

any better suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: If you divide by DC, how do you get 0.2? all the DC values should become 1

Comment: Are you just dividing by df.loc[0, 'DC']  ? Just the cell in DC not the entire DC column?

Comment: @Scott, with all the Columns in DC, e.g cell 0 - cell 428

Comment: @mozway, it was a typo error. it ought to ne `0.5`

Comment: Still unclear, that should be 1, especially given the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you want

```
for column in df.columns: 
    if column == 'DC': 
        pass # this just does nothing and skip the column
    else: 
        df[col] = df[col] / df['DC']
```